# How to use custom data types dropdownlist buttons in flutter?

Tags: flutter, enums, dropdownbutton

I want to make **drop-downlistbutton** but its list should be elements of **enum** now I tried to change the type but it showed an error now I know I could do with strings and later on use if-else to do but obviously would make the code long so is there any way like to change the string to datatype of an enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do that. Just specify the data type you want to use, here we use `DropdownButton<CustomType>`

```
enum CustomType { TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3 }

DropdownButton<CustomType>(
  onChanged: (value) => print(value),
  items: [
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text("TYPE 1"),
      value: CustomType.TYPE1,
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text("TYPE 2"),
      value: CustomType.TYPE2,
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text("TYPE 3"),
      value: CustomType.TYPE3,
    ),
  ],
)
```

Iterating over enum values

```
DropdownButton<CustomType>(
  onChanged: (value) => print(value),
  items: CustomType.values
      .map((type) => DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(type.toString().split('.')[1]),
            value: type,
          ))
      .toList(),
)
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: In this case, you have three elements so it is easy what if I have around 50 elements the code will be too long.

Comment: You can iterate over the enum values, look at the updated answer.